# what is the difference between I_DIRTY and I_DIRTY_SYNC

Tags: linux

In the fs code I see mark_inode_dirty() function which is passed with the parameter I_DIRTY and I_DIRTY_SYNC
What is the difference between both. I guess both will mark the inode as dirty and commit the changes to the 
disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: http://ehc.ac/p/mrvopensource/linux-ppc-2.6/ci/1c0eeaf5698597146ed9b873e2f9e0961edcf0f9/tree/include/linux/fs.h?barediff=2e6883bdf49abd0e7f0d9b6297fc3be7ebb2250b

I_DIRTY is a superset of I_DIRTY_SYNC:

```
#define I_DIRTY (I_DIRTY_SYNC | I_DIRTY_DATASYNC | I_DIRTY_PAGES)
```

Which are documented as:

```
I_DIRTY_SYNC        Inode itself is dirty.
I_DIRTY_DATASYNC    Data-related inode changes pending
I_DIRTY_PAGES       Inode has dirty pages.  Inode itself may be clean.
```

Comment: What is the difference of inode itself dirty and inode has dirty pages. I node has dirty pages means it has changes on cache to be pushed onto disk. Is that understanding correct. what is the difference between Data-related inode changes and inode itself is dirty.

Comment: :Thanks. I read the link you provided above. I had few doubts on the flags usage. For I_DIRTY_PAGEs - pages are dirty but inode is clean.Please explain.